# How to write a code for a dataset in which one of the columns contains punctuations, spaces and to delete the corresponding row to it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean a dataset which contain some chinese characters and get rid of those rows which contain chinese characters.

I have first tried replacing chinese characters with a space and then tried to use regex to fill the dataset with only those rows and columns which don't have the spaces and punctuations.

```
        df["reviewer_name"] = df["reviewer_name"].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','')
        df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '')
        df = df[df['comments'].str.contains(r'\W+', na=False)]
        df
```

The data is like this -

- data -
  title_id             date        Reviewer_name           comments

  258716           2019-04-21       Heap Chuan        新公寓,很干净,还有管理员接待

-Expected-
All the rows with chinese character to be gone from dataset

Answer (score 1):

Find rows containing the regular expression: rows_to_drop are the indicies of rows  containing chinese.

```
rows_to_drop1= df.loc[df["reviewer_name"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', na=False)].index
clean_df = df.drop(rows_to_drop1,axis=0)
rows_to_drop2= df.loc[df["comments"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', na=False)].index
```

Now you want to update clean_df by dropping rows_to_drop2, so set inplace=True:

```
clean_df.drop(rows_to_drop2,axis=0,inplace=True)
```

You can also do it all at once:

```
condition1 = df["reviewer_name"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', na=False)
condition2 = df["comments"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', na=False)
row_to_drop = df.loc[condition1 & condition2 ].index
clean_df = df.drop(rows_to_drop,axis=0)
```

Comment: It throws an error  in this line rows_to_drop=df.loc[df["reviewer_name"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]).index . error:  EOL while scanning string literal. I am quite new to python so please forgive me for silly questions

Comment: Here is a sample of rows :                                                                          
listing_id       id             date          reviewer_id      reviewer_name      comments                                          
                                                                                                                         
.Some of comments and reviwer_id are in chinese and my task is to remove the row wherever i find chinese characters among these two columns

Comment: There is a typo: need to close quotes after reg-ex. Now should work: rows_to_drop= df.loc[df["Reviewer_name"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]')].index

Comment: Yes, it worked for the "Reviewer_name" column but it doesn't work with the column "comments". I tried using this code                                               
rows_to_drop2 = df.loc[df["comments"].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]')].index
clean_df = df.drop(rows_to_drop2,axis=0) 
I get this error - ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: Try set na=False. I'll change it in my answer and clean it all up